# How to install on Composer on MAMP for Windows?

Tags: php, laravel, installation, composer-php

I am trying to install composer for mamp, but it keeps coming up with the same error. I tried editing the .ini file, but it still doesn't work:

> The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
> If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl

Comment: Please edit the following information into your question: 1. The output of running `php -m`. 2. What you actually did with `php.ini` - "I tried editing it" sounds like you were unable to do so.

Comment: The other ones I saw said take the ";" out of ";extension=php_openssl.dll" but it did not work

Comment: So now you have `extension=php_openssl.dll` and PHP does not complain that it can't find `php_openssl.dll`?

Comment: Yes composer still says the same thing even though I have enabled it

Comment: do you happen to have other versions of php installed (or even xampp / wamp)? You can check which php versions are configured in your PATH variable (http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/)

Comment: Yes I have several  other versions 5.4 and upwards